# Designing through class and objects in RichFaces

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I am using JSF 1.2 and RichFaces.

I am currently designing my form in JSF pages using RichFaces various tag.
I was thinking whether it is possible to design my form using RichFaces classes  instead of using the tag , so that I can make an object of the class and use it in the JSF pages and it will render the form depending upon the object.
I googled it but couldn't find any example.

Comment: Bad practice. Don't do that. You will end up in verbose and brittle code mess which is a pain to maintain because you're basically repeating the job already done by a well defined JSF page. XML based languages are much more well suited for clearly defining a tree structure. See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for the suggestion.